# Java Regex expressions for Passwords

Tags: java, regex

I've just created this class for a password validation

```
 /* 
 *  ^                         Start anchor
 *  (?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])        Ensure string has two uppercase letters.
 *  (?=.*[!@#$&*])            Ensure string has one special case letter.
 *  (?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])        Ensure string has two digits.
 *  (?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]) Ensure string has three lowercase letters.
 *  .{8}                      Ensure string is of length 8.
 *  $                         End anchor.
 */
public class PasswordUtils {

    private static final String PWD_REGEX = "^(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z])";

    /**
     * Non instantiable.
     */
    private PasswordUtils() {
        throw new AssertionError("Non instantiable");
    }

    public static boolean match (String pwd1, String pwd2) {
        return StringUtils.equals(pwd1, pwd2);
    }

    public static boolean isStrong(String password){
        return password.matches(PWD_REGEX);
     }
}
```

Then this Junit, but it seems that the pwd does not match the requirements
of the regular expression

```
private final String PWD6 = "Pi89pR&s";

@Test
public void testStrong () {
    assertTrue(PasswordUtils.isStrong(PWD6));
}
```

Comment: It's easier not to use regex. Just iterate the string one char at a time, counting the number of upper case, lower case etc. Then ensure the counts meet your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hope this will help you out..

**Regex:** `^(?=.*?[A-Z].*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z].*?[a-z].*?[a-z])(?=.*?[\d].*?[\d])(?=.*?[^\w]).{8}$`

> **1.** `^` start of string.
>
> **2.**  `(?=.*?[A-Z].*?[A-Z])` positive look ahead for two uppercase characters.
>
> **3.**  `(?=.*?[a-z].*?[a-z].*?[a-z])` positive look ahead for three lowercase characters.
>
> **4.** `(?=.*?[\d].*?[\d])` positive look ahead for two digits.
>
> **5.** `(?=.*?[^\w])` positive look ahead for non-word character
>
> **6.** `.{8}` will match exactly 8 characters.
>
> **7.** `$` end of string.

[**Regex code demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uHh6mr/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2})(?=(?:.*[0-9]){2})(?=(?:.*[!@#$&*]){1}).{8}`

The basic idea is:

`(?=(?:.*[GROUP]){NUMBER})`

Where `GROUP` is the grouping you want to match (i.e `A-Z`) and `NUMBER` is how many.

*Also note, you can use `{NUMBER,}` if you want to match `NUMBER` or more occurrences of each group.*

https://regex101.com/r/JGtIkF/1