# Java regex require at least one letter and one digit. Also allow only selected special characters

Tags: java, regex

I tried researching for this, got it to partially work but when include the special characters, it won't work. On the special characters - it is NOT required but if a special character is used, it must only be the allowed special character (`@` and `-`(dash)).

Tried this but it wont work. Anyone can help? by the way it should be at least 8 characters long

```
^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9@-]).{8,}$
```

Some examples:

```
"JohnDoe" should be invalid
"JohnDoe2" should be valid 
"22222222" should be invalid 
"22222222a" should be valid
"JohnDoe2@" should be valid
"JohnDoe2#" should be invalid
"johndoe2" should be valid
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of cases that should work and some that shouldnt?

Comment: Do you mean *require* at least one letter and one digit?

Comment: Also, Check this out - might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43833810/2341336

Comment: @barmar: sorry i meant REQUIRE at least one digit and at least one letter. and if a special character will be included, it must be only @ or - but the special character is not required

Comment: @chris: some examples -  "JohnDoe" will not work  "JohnDoe2" will work.   "22222222" will not work , "22222222a" will work. "JohnDoe2@" will work. "JohnDoe2#" will not work.  "johndoe2" will also work

Comment: @AlainDelRosario Edit the question to correct the description and add the examples.

Comment: There are many similar questions.

Comment: @barmar: done - edited question and description

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Regex expressions for Passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833712/java-regex-expressions-for-passwords)

Comment: @chris: tried this but wont work "(?=(?:.*[a-zA-Z]){1})(?=(?:.*[0-9]){1})(?=(?:.*[@-]{0}).{8,49}"     - it still accepts special chars other than @ and -

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good application for a regex.  Why don't you just scan the string, character-by-character, counting how many of each type you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`(?=(?:.*[a-zA-Z]){1,})(?=(?:.*[@-]){0,})(?=(?:.*[0-9]){1,})^[a-zA-Z0-9@-]*$`

The first section follows the pattern `(?=(?:.*[GROUP]){NUMBER})` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43833810/2341336).

Then I added the section `^[a-zA-Z0-9@-]*$` which basically says from the beginning of the string, `^`, to the end ,`$`, the only characters present should be from the set `[a-zA-Z0-9@-]`

Here is the [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QDWFDZ/1) with unit tests you provided.